# Two external/public functions calling a private function. Where to put nonReentrant()?

Tags: solidity

I have a case similar to those examples bellow.

Assuming `buy()` & `discountBuy()` has no `call`, `transfer` or `send`, would it be safe to let the `nonReentrant()` in the private `_internalBuy()`?

It seems to me that either way would work, and I kind of prefer the first option, but as other people will also read the contract when published, I wonder if they would feel safer with one or the other, or if the contract would be judged differently by auditors if I decide to get an audit.

```js
function buy() external payable {

    _internalBuy(false);
}

function discountBuy(bytes32 signedMsg, /* .. */) external payable {

    // Do some checks
    require(doesPassTests(/* ... */), "denied")

    _internalBuy(true);
}

function _internalBuy (bool applyDiscount) private nonReentrant() {
    
    uint _price = (applyDiscount ? (PRICE - discountValue): PRICE)

    someAddress.call{value: _price}("");
}
```

```js
function buy() external payable nonReentrant() {

    _internalBuy(false);
}

function discountBuy(bytes32 signedMsg, /* .. */) external payable nonReentrant() {

    // Do some checks
    require(doesPassTests(/* ... */), "denied")
    
    _internalBuy(true);
}

function _internalBuy (bool applyDiscount) private {
    
    uint _price = (applyDiscount ? (PRICE - discountValue): PRICE)

    someAddress.call{value: _price}("");
}
```

Comment: I have not write any practical code but as per theory using nonrentrant on  private method is useless. Because any one can call the external method which breaks the purpose of not executing same logic by anyone during the execution.

Simply do not use it on private or internal method always use on external and public.